# Determine which aspects hook into a given class

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Is it possible to determine which aspects hook into a given class and to gain access to their instances?

Something like:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
List<Object> aspects = getAllAspectsOf(foo);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.  For one thing, what does it mean to be an aspect of foo?  Perhaps you mean that when an advice is executed, 'foo' will be bound to the 'this()' pointcut.  Since pointcuts can be dynamically bound, any such getAllAspectsOf(foo) method will depend on which thread and what the cflow is.  I think you should be looking at using perthis or pertarget.  Then for a given instance of Foo, you can call MyAspect.aspectOf(foo).  See http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#aspect-instantiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you most likely would not be able to do any such monitoring using existing Aspect APIs, because **Aspect wrappers that intercept calls with the specific purpose of NOT being tied to any one particular component, so there would not be any natural way to detect intercepting aspects.**

That said - there might be a way you could wrap aspects inside of some sort of strategy class, however, the amount of work to maintain this would be quite significant.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.php#q:benefits

Aspects are often described as "being on top of" or "woven in with" your other code, i.e. at runtime or build time.

http://asm.ow2.org/users.html

Thus, your code would not typically be "aware" of any such aspect oriented features, given this paradigm for the implementation of aspects.

*However, if you wanted traceable aspects , you could implement some Aspect "like" features using standard java and dependency injection* - that is, by loading injected modules at runtime which implement some of the cross-cutting functionality that an aspect would implement ... but, i suspect, if you are really doing serious aspect oriented code, such an approach would fall short of your aspect oriented requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can, although, it would be technology dependent.  As far as I know, there is no way with aspectj or cglib to track and access the advice woven around a class.  You could create your advice such that it will add a reference to itself to some thread local structure that can be accessed by the advised class.  However, it would seem to defeat the purpose of aspects as a solution to cross cutting concerns if you couple your target classes to them.

Comment: I do not intend to couple the target class to the aspect. Instead i want to provide a strategy class with the target class and the strategy class then needs to access the aspect defined on the target class to register some listener. The target class is unmodified... only the strategy class has knowledge about the aspect.

Comment: @mibollma: Could you have the advice register the listener, saving you having to provide the strategy to the target instance?

Answer (score 0):

I guess to get some limited information it would need **to change the weaver** so it saves some log of its work into the augmented class, so you can later read it. But do not expect much - AFAIK aspects may not exist as no run-time types at all. I wonder - is there any framework doing that?